# Java: Any exposed service for selecting the correct overload

Tags: java, algorithm, overloading

In our platform, we need to come up with a way to pick the correct overload of a method given that we know information of the type of arguments used to invoke it

Earlier we were relying on Java lang itself to pick the right overload for us, but now with some other changes, we need to come up with an algorithm which picks the right overload for us given the method parameters and the argument types

So, I am interested to know, if there is any exposed service or something like that, where I can pass in the actual arguments used to invoke the function and the function parameters and the service returns back a rank or something which I can use to compare and pick the right function Instance?

```
1) Get all the methods defined with the same name and same number of parameters. These are our set of candidate functions.
2) Once we have this set of candidate functions , we loop through each one of them and do a instance of check with the argument types and pick a function
3) Use this picked function parameters to do an instance of checks with other function parameters that way we pick the top most subclass in case instance of passes for multiple method definitions ( example provided below)
4) In case we still have more than one candidate, we throw the ambigous method definition exception exactly the way that java does currently.
```

Example:

```
Class Exception2 extends Exception1
Class Exception1 extends MyException
Class MyException
```

now if I have methods defined as

```
func(Exception2 ex2)
func(Exception1 ex1)
```

and we invoke this function using

```
func(new MyException())
```

In this case I need to make sure that func (Exception2) gets picked and not func (Exception1)

Thoughts?

Comment: `func(Exception1)` is not an appropriate overload for a parameter of type `MyException`. Neither is `func(Exception2)`. I suggest you allow Java to pick its own overload.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a class' methods via reflection. The full doc can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)

Short example:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("my.package.MyClass");
Object t = c.newInstance();
c.getDeclaredMethods();
Method m ; // some method from the above list
m.invoke(t, arg1, arg2 ..)
```

You can find out more about a method before you try to invoke it, like checking its formal arguments with `getParameterTypes()`, name, return type, etc. More info can be found for Methods [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html).